# Create Ec2 instance and install Python package using Ansible Playbook

Tags: ansible

I've created an ansible playbook for create an Ec2 instance and Install python to connect the server via ssh.

The Playbook successfully created an EC2 instance but it doesn't install the python on newly created Ec2 Instance instead it installing the python on my Master Machine.

Can someone help me to resolve this.

My Code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  remote_user: ubuntu
  become: yes
  tasks:
- name: I'm going to create a Ec2 instance
  ec2:
    key_name: yahoo
    instance_type: t2.micro
    region: "ap-south-1"
    image: ami-0860c9429baba6ad2
    count: 1
    vpc_subnet_id: subnet-aa84fbe6
    assign_public_ip: yes
  tags:
    - creation

- name: Going to Install Python
  apt:
    name: python
    state: present
  tags:
    - Web

- name: Start the service
  service:
    name: python
    state: started
  tags:
    - start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is shown in [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html#examples), `ec2:` operations should be combined with `add_host:` in order to "pivot" off of localhost over to the newly provisioned instance, which one cannot add to an inventory file because it doesn't exist yet

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: I'm going to create a Ec2 instance
      ec2:
        ...etc etc
      register: run_instances
    - name: Add new instance to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groupname: just_launched
      loop: "{{ run_instances.instances }}"

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      delegate_to: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
      wait_for_connection:
        delay: 60
        timeout: 320
      loop: "{{ run_instances.instances }}"

- hosts: just_launched
  # and now you can do fun things to those ec2 instances
```

I suspect your question about "installing python" is unrelated, but just in case: if you genuinely really do need to add python to those ec2 instances, you cannot use most ansible modules to do that because they're written in python. But that is what the [`raw:` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/raw_module.html) is designed to fix

```yaml
- hosts: just_launched
  # you cannot gather facts without python, either
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - raw: |
      echo watch out for idempotency issues with your playbook using raw
      yum install python

  - name: NOW gather the facts
    setup:

  - command: echo and now you have working ansible modules again
```

I also find your invocation of `service: { name: python, state: started }` suspicious, but I would guess it has not run yet due to your question here